# Understanding Junction

Tags: windows-10, junction, mklink

Most games I play stores its "save" data files in either

```
"C:\Users\ShortQuestion\My Documents"
```

or

```
"C:\Users\ShortQuestion\Saved Games"
```

Since I don't want all these save files filling up my C drive, I was looking for a solution to get these files automatically saved to another drive. In my search I stumbled upon `mklink /J`

My understanding so far is that if I would use

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\ShortQuestion\My Documents" "D:\Saves"
```

Every file created in "My Documents" folder will now get actually saved in "D:\Saves" folder not taking space in C drive. Is my understanding correct?

Since I need to delete `"C:\Users\ShortQuestion\My Documents"` for this to work I want to make sure that I'm understanding the command correctly.

Also will it be possible to link 2 different folders to the same target? e.g:

```
mklink /J "C:\Users\ShortQuestion\My Documents" "D:\Saves"
mklink /J "C:\Users\ShortQuestion\Saved Games" "D:\Saves"
```

Comment: Consider that you are making a junction rather than a hard link. Yes, technically it is possible to link two symlinks to one file. I think this is the case with hard links as well. Check the Microsoft Docs on mklink and do a trial of this with two new folders before actually doing this on real data. It is possible to lose that data if you put them in the wrong order.

Comment: In addition to what Varun said, I would take it a step further and backup your saved game data prior to any junction script that runs, as they can sometimes misbehave and can wipe your data from its original location.

Comment: Thank you both, I gave it a shot with two dummy folders just to make sure it would work and it did. I also backed up data to be extra sure. I just wasn't sure this would work with those folders since they are system folders and not "normal folders" but atm it seems like everything went fine

Comment: My Documents is already a junction in Windows 10 for c:\users\shortquestion\Documents folder. Also have you tried changing the location of "documents" and "Saved games" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: Yes.

There's no real limit on the number of symlinks you can have pointing to a given target folder, just like there's no real limit to the number of .lnk files you can have pointing to a give target.